# WooCommerce using Paypal Pro Hosted package to integrate checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, subscriptions

I'm looking at integrating the Paypal checkout into my wooCommerce site and need a little help on what to change in the wooCommerce theme files to redirect the Paypal express checkout to the hosting package.

The website is UK based with a UK Paypal account and the wooCommerce uses subscriptions.

The Paypal documentation gives this example code:

```
<form action="https://securepayments.paypal.com/cgi-bin/acquiringweb" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
<input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="50">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="HNZ3QZMCPBAAA"> <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale"> <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://yourwebsite.com/receipt_page.html">
<input type="submit" name="METHOD" value="Pay"> </form>
```

I'm just not sure if I can change the wooCommerce to use the above instead of what it does currently?

wooCommerce offer 2 plugins but the 'Pro' one doesn't support subscriptions and the 'Advanced' one is only for the US, so I'm kind of stuck and need to look at alternatives.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It exists a plugin for PayPal Pro Hosted : http://codecanyon.net/item/paypal-pro-hosted-solution-for-woocommerce/7360563

Hope this will help!